# Format changes importing to access from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am importing data from excel into Access and, for some of the files, my 11 digit data starting with 2 leading 0s will be trimmed to 9 without the leading 0s and it's messing up my SQL queries. I double check and I'm certain that the cells are correct in the original excel file. How do I prevent trimming when it imports? Alternatively, how do I change the format of the column to force it to be 11 digits? I couldn't see that as an option in the ribbon.

Below is the code I'm using to import:

```
Public Sub ImportXLSS(fileName As String, tableName As String)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the Excel columns formatted as text? Could run an UPDATE action on the imported data to make sure column has 11 characters using Format() function or use Format() function in SELECT queries.

Comment: They're formatted as "Special". I used .EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "00000000000" to change it. Is that the problem? Is there another way to format the columns

Comment: Try Text option "treated as text even when a number is in the cell". In my test, the leading zeros are retained.

Comment: I do that because the data doesn't come with 11 digits. My vba code that preps the data in excel changes it to 11 digits. Does it need to append the 00? In short, I have 9 digits in excel, and I want to change it to 11 and export it to access all using vba

Comment: Exactly how does VBA prep the data in Excel? Make sure the zeros really are there or modify data after import as already suggested.